# Checking if network is connect (wifi or mobile data) android java

Tags: android, networking

I am currently detecting if the WIFI is connected with the following code:

```
        BroadcastReceiver wifiStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int wifiStateExtra = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE,
                    WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);
            Log.v("Log","Wifi Toggled");

        }
    };

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    context.registerReceiver(wifiStateReceiver, intentFilter);

    wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

This code will currently tell me whenever the wifi is toggled on or off. I am looking for something like this, that will send me a notification anytime my network status is changed, i.e. when I do or don't have a connection(wifi OR mobile data) to the internet. Is there something like a NetworkManger I can use that will tell me if the network status has changed?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the official documentation for [determining and monitoring the connectivity status](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring).

#### To determine if you have an internet connection

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
 (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                      activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

#### To determine the type of your internet connection

(Device connectivity can be provided by mobile data, WiMAX, Wi-Fi, and ethernet connections)

```
boolean isWiFi = activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
```

#### Monitor for changes in connectivity

Apps targeting Android 7.0 (API level 24) and higher do not receive CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcasts if they declare the broadcast receiver in their manifest. Apps will still receive CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcasts if they register their BroadcastReceiver with Context.registerReceiver() and that context is still valid.

Answer (score 2):

**Android Internet connection check For API 29+**

```
private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "NetworkStatusExample";

ConnectivityManager connMgr =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
boolean isWifiConn = false;
boolean isMobileConn = false;
for (Network network : connMgr.getAllNetworks()) {
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(network);
    if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
        isWifiConn |= networkInfo.isConnected();
    }
    if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
        isMobileConn |= networkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Wifi connected: " + isWifiConn);
Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Mobile connected: " + isMobileConn);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    val connMgr = getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

    var isWifiConn = false
    var isMobileConn = false
    for (network in connMgr.allNetworks) {
        val networkInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(network)
        if (networkInfo!!.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            isWifiConn = isWifiConn or networkInfo!!.isConnected
        }
        if (networkInfo!!.type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            isMobileConn = isMobileConn or networkInfo!!.isConnected
        }
    }
    Log.d("DEBUG_TAG", "Wifi connected: $isWifiConn")
    Log.d("DEBUG_TAG", "Mobile connected: $isMobileConn")
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace the deprecated **isConnected()** method in Android, you can use the **hasTransport()** method along with NetworkCapabilities.

```
private void checkInternetConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
    if (capabilities != null) {
        if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
            status.setText("Connected");
            type.setText("Type: Wi-Fi");
        } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
            status.setText("Connected");
            type.setText("Type: Mobile Data");
        } // Add more Transports
    } else {
        status.setText("Not Connected");
        type.setText("Type: None of above");
    }
}
```